# Errors symbol is shown when importing CW Endless Adapter project

Tags: android, cwac-endless

I have downloaded the zip file to implement the CW-Endless Adapter to my customlistview from this [link](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless). When I extracted it and imported to eclipse, the **!** is shown in red color as shown in the below picture. Can someone please help me resolve this?

[image]

When I rightclick on the `project --> Java BuildPath --> Libraries -->` When I mouse hover on the first red cross symbol it shows the projected one as shown in the below figure.